# AngularJS - Using $setValidity with ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having a bit of a problem (mostly because of my lack of knowledge of AngularJS directives). I am using the Rating Directive directive from the UI Bootstrap library combined with my own custom validation. Multiple rating directive instances are created using `ng-repeat` from an object array from my controller. I use other scope variables to set the default "Rate Me" text, the custom CSS classes '`ratingOptions.ratingStates`' and the max value limitiations '`ratingOptions.max`'. All is working as desired... This is my directive code in the view (please note that the container form is called "`categoryRatingFrom`":

```
<div data-ng-repeat="cats in categories">
    <div data-ng-form name="RatingFrom">
        <div class="row no-bottom-padding">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">@{{ cats.name }}</label>

            <div class="col-sm-8">

                <div class="no-outline"
                     data-rating
                     data-ng-model="cats.value"
                     data-max="ratingOptions.max"
                     data-rating-states="ratingOptions.ratingStates"
                     data-on-hover="cats.onHover(value)"
                     data-on-leave="cats.onLeave()"
                     data-rating-validate > <!-- Notice the custom directive -->
                </div>
                @{{ cats.hoverState || cats.items[cats.value - 1].name || rateMe }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I wish to set the directive instance to invalid should a value not being set, the default value is zero but the user must enter a value from 1 to `ratingOptions.max` (which is currently 6). I have a custom directive to validate this called `ratingValidate`. This is being invoked/bootstrapped and I am able to determine the current value of each directive instance, however I wish to initially set the directive/form-item to invalid and once the user selects a value we set the directive /form-item/instance to valid. This should be fairly easy but with using an `ng-repeat` I am unsure how to reference the specific form item. If anyone could help explain what I need to do whilst I experiment and search the AngularJS docs I would be most appreciative. This is my directive...

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('ratingValidate', function () {

       // ratingValidate
        return {
            restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
            require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                // do nothing if no ng-model
                if (!ngModel) {
                    return;
                }

                // Listen for change events to enable binding
                element.bind('click change', function () {

                    console.log(element[0], attrs);
                    if(attrs.ariaValuenow === 0){
                        ngModel.$setValidity('', false); // What goes here??? How do I reference the item?
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('', false); // What goes here??? How do I reference the item?
                    }

                });

            }
        };
    })
;
```

Answer (score 2):

## How Angular Validation Works

Angular uses the 'name' attribute to create the $scope variables used for validation.

For example, if you have an input field with a 'required' attribute:

```
<form name="myform">
   <input name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" type="text" required/>
</form>
```

Then to access the validation properties on $scope, you would do:

```
var validationFailed = $scope.myform.firstname.$error.required;
```

Where $error is an object that has 'required' as a Boolean property.

In the 'required' directive, you would see something like this:

```
                if(attrs.value == ''){
                    ngModel.$setValidity('required', true); // failed validation
                } else {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('required', false); // passed validation
                }
```

You can pass any string to $setValidity, and it will set the $error property for you. For example, if you did:

```
$setValidity('test', true)
```

Then there would be an $error property named 'test' and it would be set to true. You can then access the property like this:

```
$scope.myform.firstname.$error.test
```

Other validation properties that are available are:

```
$scope.myform.firstname.$valid
$scope.myform.firstname.$invalid
$scope.myform.firstname.$pristine
$scope.myform.$valid
$scope.myform.$invalid
$scope.myform.$pristine
```

Hope this helps to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this I added the following to the directive HTML:

```
name="rating@{{$index}}
```

and in the directive

```
ngModel.$setValidity(attrs.name, true); // or false depending on the condition
```